# Conditional scraping of already scraped items from an index page

Tags: scrapy

I'm trying to scrape a movie reviews site using python scrapy.

In the index page of the movie reviews, items are ordered by relevance, so items cannot be sorted in a way new items appear at the top of the list.

Thus, I want to be able to browse the index daily and skip those reviews I've already scraped.

I was thinking on exporting each review into a single file.

Is is possible to check whether a file already exists from the spider?
Is this the best practice to do it?

I'm new in web-scraping and I don't know if this is a good practice.

Comment: please: *scrape* not *scrap*.  I chortly childishly every time I see phrases like 'conditional scrapping' (yeah, we can scrap that one).  I know I'm immature, but still... did brighten my day though :)

Comment: you could check if each item you scraped has a unique id like a product id and use that to identity if you have alreadys scraped it

Comment: Yes, I can do that: I'm storing the unique URL of each review. But, where do I store them for the spider to read? How do I read them? what is the best practice?

Comment: If the review has a unique id or you can assign them some unique id then you can create a pipeline that reads the items already scraped in its init method and passes the item list to the spider. The spider can then filter out urls based on the list of already scraped items.